# how to delete some layers of Resnet?

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet

I tried to delete the last fc layer of the resnet34 using the following code:

```
resnet34 = models.resnet34(pretrained=False)
mymodel =  torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(resnet34.children())[:-1]))
checkpoint = torch.load('./resnet18-f37072fd.pth')
mymodel.load_state_dict(checkpoint,strict=False)
```

but the problem is that the name of the layer has changed after the operation.

the original name is `avgpool`

[image: the layer is "avgpool"]

but now it is `8`

[image: now the layer is "8"]

when I add the pre-trained weights, it shows the names are not matched.
How should I keep the name of the layers unchanged while deleting the last layer?

I tried to delete the last "fc" layer of the resnet34, but all of the layer names have changed.

Comment: You can set the last layer to the identify function. model.fc = nn.Identity()

Comment: I find a new way, just use
'
del model.fc
'

Comment: @ChenChao That doesn't throw an error when you call `model.forward`?

Comment: yes, when u load the pre-trained model, u can set the strict as False, it will work.